# «Не называл» или «ни называл»?

Tags: пунктуация, частица, не-или-ни

«Не» или «ни»? И как правильно должно быть оформлено это предложение?

*Кем он ее только не (ни) называл: и ангелом, и пудельком, и хромоногой курочкой?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В данном предложении следует писать частицу НЕ. В целом смысл понятен, но двоеточие, на мой взгляд, вносит некоторый диссонанс. Я бы оформил так:

*Кем он ее только **не** называл! И ангелом, и пудельком, и хромоногой курочкой.*

(Называл-то он ее по-всякому, а вот кем **не** называл – можно только гадать.)

[Правописание частицы ***ни***](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=82) (Розенталь)

> 5. В самостоятельных восклицательных и вопросительных предложениях (часто со словами ***только, уж***) употребляется частица ***не***, а в придаточных частях сложноподчиненного предложения (с уступительным оттенком значения) — частица ***ни***. Ср.:
>    *Куда только он **не** обращался! (‘обращался во многие места’)
>
>    Куда только он **ни** обращался, везде встречал сочувственное отношение.
>
>    Что мать **не** делала для больного сына!
>
>    Чего мать **ни** делала для больного сына, как ни пыталась помочь ему, но спасти его не смогла.*
>    Ср. также: *На какие только ухищрения **не** пускается человек, чтобы не пропасть, добиться счастья, какие только профессии себе **не** придумывает, а удачи всё нет и нет; Чего только **не** дают, а они ни в какую* — с помощью союза *а* соединены самостоятельные предложения, в первой части нет придаточной части с уступительным оттенком значения, поэтому пишется **не**.

*Где он только не бывал! Чего он только не видал!* (Грибоедов)

*Особенно Толстого не любил Крылов и называл его… да **как только не называл***. [М. Б. Бару. Таракан на канате // «Волга», 2016]

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки. Но логика, конечно, у великого и могучего хромает. "Не" это всегда отрицательная частица. Для прочих целей есть специальное "ни". Но что она отрицает в "Куда только он не обращался!"? Ничего.

Comment: Это как вопрос: *Куда он не обращался?* Обращался и туда, и сюда, и много куда,  а вот только сюда **не** обращался.

Comment: Ах вот оно в чем дело. Тогда ок. Понятно почему в одиночных фразах превалирует не, а в составных ни. Но остается вопрос почему нельзя писать в этом предложении ни. https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE+%D0%BD%D0%B8

Comment: Правописание НЕ/НИ – довольно сложная тема. Могут быть и спорные моменты, и ошибки (особенно в новых изданиях, где не всегда корректура-редактура на высоте).

Answer (score 1):

**Ни** и только **ни**

Аргумент 1:

Есть такое правило (моё собственное, кстати), что **не** можно ставить там, где можно писать без не. У нас в предложении без ни/не будет явная ошибка, значит пишем **ни**.

Аргумент 2:

Ясно, что у нас не отрицательное предложение, а утвердительное. Значит ставим не отрицательное `не`, а усилительное `ни`

Аргумент 3:

У усилительной частицы **ни** и усилительной частицы-союза **ни..ни..** фактически одни и те же усилительные функции в предложении. Разница лишь в количестве усиливаемых элементов. Добавим в наше предложение еще один усиливаемый элемент. Само предложение при этом не изменится, зато правильность написания станет очевидной.

```
Как он её только ни называл, ни именовал. И ангелом, и пудельком, и хромоногой курочкой.
```

Насчет пунктуации я не силен. Но очевидно, что двоеточие/точка не ошибка.

PS
А вот например у Стругацких ошибка:

```
Андрей, как не старался упираться ногами, подлетал и падал в точности на острие проклятой пружины.
```

Потому что получается, что Андрей не старался как-то. А раз он не старался, то не удивительно, что подлетал. Предложение теряет смысл. Но и грамматически оно не корректно.